# Wordpress adding inline style can't remove it

Tags: css

Looks like wordpress is adding inline style.  In the style is shows this link http://wp.me/PEmnE-Bt.  I don't know where the style is being stored (In DB or a file?) I can't remove it or find where the inline style is being added.  Anyone know?

Comment: It was stored in the database.  After several searches on the web I figured it out.  Data was stored in posts table in the post_content field.  Deleting the data fixed it.